# UV Mapping Problems

Tags: 3d, blender, uv-mapping

I'm creating an alien in blender, doing my best to base it on the guys from toy story. When I create the UV Map and colour it, import it back in then take a look at it in a seperate window there is alot of black segments on it. Ive tried the whole SMART UV PROJECT option aswell but I still get the same thing. What have I done wrong here?

[image]

Update: Followed advice below and can now colour without the black segments seen in the first pic, however I am now seeing lines on my alien, is this because of GIMP? (Im using GIMP to colour my guy)

[image]

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like you have some quads that aren't being included in the UV projection (because they are still taking up the whole UV square). Also, if this is a subdivision model, try casting to a mesh first and then see how it looks.

Answer (score 3):

First off, make sure you're adding a material on your mesh, then add the texture, set it as "image or movie", and chose "Coordinates: UV":

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yea I have been doing that, im still getting the above result.

Comment: Do you get the same result if you simply load the image on the UV unwrap and set your viewport mode to textured? Finally, if noone has a better suggestion, make available a link with your blender project and texture and I'll try looking into it.

Comment: Sorry Im a blender noob! How would i go about doing that?

Comment: Make 2 viewports: drag upper-right corner of current viewport to left -> Click on lower-left Cube icon, set one of the viewports to UV/Image Editor. Still here, from lower menu select image->new->ok. Select your mesh in the other viewport. TAB to go to edit mode. Select all faces (A). If you've properly UV-unrapped them you should see that unwrapping in the viewport you set to UV/Image editor. Select that viewport (the one with the UVs), and from the lower menu, select Image->open Image and select your texture. In the viewport with the mesh, select View Port Shading:texture from lower menu.

Comment: Thanks so much, works perfectly!! :) One last question, when I do that the colours work perfect, but I now have permanent lines on my alien, how do i remove those?

Comment: Well, do you mean the texture is still not placed the way you want on your mesh? If so you should look into UV unwrapping. Start by looking at how to mark seams on edges and how to use the "Follow active quad" option. If it's NOT that, and the lines you mention are not from the texture image or the way it's placed on the mesh, please update yoru question with a screenshot depicting the issue.

Comment: This was pretty handy ... http://vimeo.com/26955480 .... Im just colouring the map in GIMP, i think that is my problem now! Will add a screenshot of this below the question sure

Comment: Ok, I see your problem (from the 2nd screen shot). Try this: split to 2 viewports, create a new image in one of them, use the other to export your UVs on that image, then in the UV/Image viewport, go to  lower menu, UVs->Export UV Layout (and save it as PNG). Load this into photoshop, add a new layer, paint your texture on that new layer (using the UV layout image as guide), then hide the UV layer, and only save your texture layer as a single image (i recommend 32 bit PNG  or TIFF). Then go back to blender, and in that same viewport with the UVs load your texuture. now the lines should be gone

Comment: I dont have photoshop, working in GIMP and have until Thursday to get it done! Its the layers thats annoying me, googling how to sort those now but finding it difficult cause im a GIMP noob aswell lol

Comment: Well, about that (ps and gimp) of you want something simpler (but with far less options) try paint.net (google it). It has a very basic layer and brushes system